# Does Bloatware on a brand new PC create security risks?

Tags: software, risk

Some new computers come with software I don't need or want.  It is not advertised as part of the product I am purchasing.  Generally this is called Bloatware.

> ### Bloatware
>
> 1.(n) Software that comes pre-installed on a computer. Bloatware generally comes on a PC made by a major manufacturer (i.e. HP, Dell, Toshiba). Most Bloatware is considered to be a useless piece of software that is intended for no other purpose than taking up hard drive space. [Source](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bloatware)

Does or can this preinstalled Bloatware create any security risks?

Comment: That definition is very poor. The programs have a purpose ...

Comment: Here's a more reasoned definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-installed_software . and it answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Any software is of course bound to have vulnerabilities; Nonetheless there have been a couple of high-profile cases in these last few years relating to bloatware or preinstalled utilities

Lenovo/Superfish: A Tool called Superfish Visual Search was shipped on Lenovo consumer laptops since late 2014. It contained a self-signed root certificate that made the machines vulnerable to MITM attacks.

HP/Conexant: In 2017 it was discovered that the audio drivers and tool on certain HP models contained a bug where all keystrokes would be logged to a file called MicTray.log. This most likely was a bug when the previous debugging mechanism via OutputDebugString() was changed and subsequently not removed